# Input Validation and spaces

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have the Input below using React Native.

```
<View style={ styles.container }>
        <Input 
        placeholder="Add new chat"
        value={input}
        onChangeText={(text) => setInput(text)}
        leftIcon={
            <Icon name="wechat" type="antdesign" size={24} color="black" />
        }
        />

        <Pressable style={styles.buttonAdd} onPress={createChat}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Create</Text>
        </Pressable>

    </View>
```

If i type nothing then i get my alert which is fine however if i put 1 or + spaces the data gets submited. How can i disallow the submit and so set the alert when there is only spaces?

```
    const [input, setInput] = useState("");

const createChat = async () => {
    if(!input) {
        alert("The chat name cannot be blank");
        return;
    }
    await db
    .collection("chats")
    .add({
        chatName: input
    })
    .then(() => {
        navigation.goBack();
    })
    .catch(() => {
        alert(error);
    })
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just remove all spaces and check if the string is still longer than zero characters.

e.g.:

```js
const submit = () => {
    if (input.replaceAll(' ', '').length > 0){
        // your submit logic here
    }
}
```

otherwise you could also test for regex, but this might be overkill for your needs.

Comment: You can also use [`input.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) to remove trailing and leading whitespace from a string.

Answer (score 1):

As `input` is a string, you can `trim` your string to remove any whitespaces from either end of the string.

Notice `trim()` will remove whitespaces from either end of the string, not the spaces in between words.

```js
const string = "   A string with spaces at end  ";
console.log(string.trim());

const string_with_only_space = "      ";
console.log(string_with_only_space.trim());

if(!string_with_only_space.trim()) {
  console.log("STRING IS EMPTY");
} else {
  console.log("STRING IS NOT EMPTY");
}
```

You can change your if condition to

```js
if(!input.trim()) {
  alert("The chat name cannot be blank");
  return;
}
```